# How to open URL from JSON push notification Android in MainActivity with Parse.com?

Tags: android, json, notifications, parse-platform, push

How can we specify a destination url for a push message ? My ap is a webapp viewer, so only webpage are displayed.

Tried lot a things but nothing seems to work. I'm new to android dev.

My MainActivity loads a url at app startup. I'd like when the user click on the notification, this start url is modified by the one in the notification.

```
String load_url = getString(R.string.load_url);
browser.loadUrl(load_url);
```

Could you explain to me with code how to do that ? I'm learning it too.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static variable in your MainActivity ex.

```
static String sNotificationUrl = "";
```

In your intent service where the notification is received set the static variable on your main activity to the value ex.

```
MainActivity.sNotificationUrl = sUrlFromNotification;
```

Then in your main activity in the onCreate method do something like this:

```
if (sNotificationUrl != "")
{
    myWebView.loadUrl(sNotificationUrl);
    sNotification = "";         
}
```